# How to rename an element in the XML generated with the "ID" transformation

Tags: xml, transformation, abap

I want to generate XML from an internal table using the `ID` XML transformation, but some of the XML element names need to be personalized.

**Program:**

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_vbpa,
         parvw TYPE vbpa-parvw,
       END OF t_vbpa,
       BEGIN OF t_vbap,
         matnr TYPE vbap-matnr,
         vbpas TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t_vbpa WITH EMPTY KEY,
       END OF t_vbap,
       BEGIN OF t_vbak,
         vbeln TYPE vbak-vbeln,
         vbaps TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t_vbap WITH EMPTY KEY,
       END OF t_vbak.

DATA: vbak TYPE t_vbak.

vbak = VALUE #( vbeln = '13'
                vbaps = VALUE #(
                      ( matnr = 'C20050'
                        vbpas = VALUE #(
                              ( parvw = 'AG' ) ) ) ) ).

" Generate a default XML
DATA xml_out TYPE string.
CALL TRANSFORMATION ('ID')
   SOURCE vbak = vbak
   RESULT XML xml_out.
```

**Result in `xml_out`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0">
<asx:values>
<VBAK>
<VBELN>13</VBELN>
<VBAPS>
    <item>
        <MATNR>C20050</MATNR>
        <VBPAS>
            <item>
                <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
            </item>
        </VBPAS>
    </item>
</VBAPS>
</VBAK>
</asx:values>
</asx:abap>
```

I want to rename the first `item` element into `item_VBAP` and the second `item` element into `item_VBPA`, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0">
<asx:values>
<VBAK>
<VBELN>13</VBELN>
<VBAPS>
    <item_VBAP>
        <MATNR>C20050</MATNR>
        <VBPAS>
            <item_VBPA>
                <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
            </item_VBPA>
        </VBPAS>
    </item_VBAP>
</VBAPS>
</VBAK>
</asx:values>
</asx:abap>
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Edit your answer please. Show us the source structure and the ABAP code for the transforming.

Answer (score 4):

The `ID` transformation is provided by SAP and cannot be personalized.

Instead, write an [XSLT](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/a8/824c3c66177414e10000000a114084/frameset.htm) or [Simple Transformation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_st.htm) using the transaction code `SE80` or `STRANS` and specify its name after `CALL TRANSFORMATION` in place of `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @vwegert answer, here is an example of simple transformation :

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates">

  <tt:root name="VBAK"/>

  <tt:template>
    <VBAK>
      <VBELN tt:value-ref="VBAK.VBELN"/>
      <VBAPS>
        <tt:loop ref="VBAK.VBAPS">
          <line_VBAP>
            <MATNR tt:value-ref="$ref.MATNR"/>
            <VBPAS>
              <tt:loop ref="$ref.VBPAS">
                <line_VBPA>
                  <PARVW tt:value-ref="$ref.PARVW"/>
                </line_VBPA>
              </tt:loop>
            </VBPAS>
          </line_VBAP>
        </tt:loop>
      </VBAPS>
    </VBAK>
  </tt:template>

</tt:transform>
```